# Framework selector issue

Tags: javascript, frameworks, return, selector

I have this selector code for my framework and I'm having an issue on something.

```js
function $elect(id) {
    if (!(this instanceof $elect)) {
        return new $elect(id);
    }
    this.elm = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

I've assigned some methods to this and so far it's working fine. I also want to use this without methods. Like `var input = $elect('inputbox');` but this doesn't work.

```js
var input1 = $elect('inputbox');
var input2 = document.getElementById('inputbox');
```

They don't return the same thing. First one returns `[object Object]` which is wrong, and the second one returns `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]`. It should be returning like the second. How can I achieve this?

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sKPCK/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an object then don't create one, just return the element from the function

```
function $elect(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Comment: Haha. Well, I'll be using its methods. Isn't there a way that I can do both?

Comment: +1 yes Musa is right but you can also do it i another way. return object so you can call another method on it like `$elect('mid').find('mmmid')` and add a method like getDom to get Element. like `$elect('mid').getDom()`.

Comment: @akinuri in your post you said `I also want to use this without methods.`

Comment: @Musa I never said I don't want an object. I want to use it with and without methods. That's why I used 'also' in there... I'm gonna have to create a method to get the element. Just wanted to know if there is a way of doing it without using a method.